# Where is the Fall located in the Colony in Total Recall (2012)?

Tags: total-recall-2012

In the 2012 remake of 'Total Recall', workers from 'the Colony' (Australia) get to the United Federation of Britain, by way of a gravity elevator called 'The Fall'.

Which current Australian city is near to where the Fall located in the film?

*Please note, I am aware of the factual inaccuracies in the film, I am just asking where it is located in the film*

Comment: Well if this [tunnel to the other side of the Earth map service](http://www.freemaptools.com/tunnel-to-other-side-of-the-earth.htm) is correct (and the tunnel went directly through the center of Earth), then such a tunnel from anywhere in Britain would come out South/South East of **New Zealand.**

Comment: @AndrewThompson yes, I am aware of the inaccuracies in the film in this regard (edited that in). I am asking where it is located, *in the film*?

Comment: Was it ever mentioned?  I don't recall.  I don't **remember** seeing any of the iconic structures that are usually used to reference my home city of Sydney ( but then, maybe that was simply because I thought it was a **forgettable** film ;) ).

Comment: Maybe it is not Sydney - I don't think it was mentioned specifically in the film.

Comment: *"Maybe it is not Sydney.."*  Maybe not.  But then, I'd (crudely) estimate that of Australian cities identified in movies, Sydney would account for at least half of them.  Melbournians OTOH, would point out that is simply because Sydneysiders are obsessed with themselves, and would expect that any movie filmed in our *state* has at least a token scene with both the Sydney Opera House (designed, Melbourne points out, by a Dane) and Sydney Harbour/The Harbour Bridge (built with money borrowed from Great Britain - ..we're just sayin') in a single 10 second shot.

Comment: Well, I am in Brisbane, but are aware of the interstate rivalry (and I agree, the movie was a forgettable farce).

Answer (score 3):

The graphic at the start of the film indicates the entire continent of Australia has effectively become one major city, with the entrance to The Fall coming out in the heart of the continent so likely Alice Springs.

There are no Australian hallmarks in the film as the production was shot with 'The Colony' originally going to be dubbed 'New Asia'.  That was changed to increase the film's multi-cultural appeal.